# query set value with data from related table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so, i have done a big mistake when i designing my table for `salesreport` that looks like this

```
+----+------------+--------------+-------+
| id | company_id | company_code | value |
+----+------------+--------------+-------+
|  1 |          0 |           67 |   100 |
|  2 |          0 |           55 |   200 |
+----+------------+--------------+-------+
```

i just recently notice it and add new column called `company_id` which is in the company table that looks like this

```
+----+--------------+------+
| id | company_code | name |
+----+--------------+------+
|  1 |           55 | XX   |
|  2 |           67 | XA   |
+----+--------------+------+
```

in the past i create relationship with `company_code` since i thought it will always unique but not auto increment, the code is created manually from company list in existing record.

i then realise that it will be better to create a relationship between table by using `id` so instead of using `company_code` it should be `company_id` on my salesreport table that pointing to `id` column in company table

and now there is more than a thousand record that already in mysql database that referencing relationship using `company_code` and i want to know is there one times mysql query that i can run to fix it?

and i come up with this kind of query

```
UPDATE salesreport SET company_id = '1' WHERE company_code = '67';
```

but i think since both tables `company` and `salesreport` already had a relationship why can't it just like this

```
UPDATE salesreport SET company_id = company.id WHERE company_code = company.company_code;
```

but i don't think it will be work, it needs more query to know that i selecting `company` table and then match `salesreport.company_code` with `company.company_code` and if it is match then set `salesreport.company_id` with `company.id`

well i think that is how it goes... but i have no idea what is the query to do just that.. so maybe someone can help me and provide a lazy-elegant solution to this.

thank you by the way.

Comment: Use `UPDATE` + `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to your request:

```
UPDATE salesreport
LEFT JOIN company ON company.company_code = salesreport.company_code
SET salesreport.company_id = company.id;
```

I have created a SQLFiddle for you to test the results: http://rextester.com/HNJ85353

Herу is a full test case:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p1929_salesreport (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                          company_id INTEGER,
                         company_code INTEGER,
                         value INTEGER);

INSERT INTO p1929_salesreport (company_id, company_code, value) VALUES (0, 67, 100);
INSERT INTO p1929_salesreport (company_id, company_code, value) VALUES (0, 55, 200);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p1929_company (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                     company_code INTEGER,
                     name TEXT);

INSERT INTO p1929_company (company_code, name) VALUES (55, "XX");
INSERT INTO p1929_company (company_code, name) VALUES (67, "XA");

/* before changes */
SELECT * FROM p1929_company;
SELECT * FROM p1929_salesreport;

/* actual query */
UPDATE p1929_salesreport
LEFT JOIN p1929_company ON p1929_company.company_code = p1929_salesreport.company_code
SET p1929_salesreport.company_id = p1929_company.id;

/* after changes */
SELECT * FROM p1929_salesreport;

DROP TABLE p1929_salesreport;
DROP TABLE p1929_company;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update with a join to your other table

```
UPDATE salesreport s 
  LEFT JOIN company c on s.company_code = c.company_code
SET s.company_id = c.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE into salesreport S
USING(select id, company_code, name from Company) C
ON(S.company_code=C.company_code)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET S.company_id = C.id
```

you can try this. this will update Salesreport table using company table when both company code matches.

Answer (score 0):

You could update using an inner join  eg:

```
  UPDATE salesreport s 
  INNER JOIN company c  ON s.company_code = c.company_code 
  set s.company_id = c.id
```